# Problem opening and reading Windows NotePad document with Unicode in Ubuntu

Tags: gedit, unicode

I opened a Windows NotePad document in Ubuntu, using Text Editor(gedit), which was in Unicode format and the document opened with a yellow heading section containing error messages:

> There was a problem opening the file “[filename and path]”.

> The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
> You can also choose another character encoding and try again."

With two buttons for the options: "Retry" and "Edit Anyway" and beneath the error message, another button with the label beside it: "Character Encoding" and which allows a drop-down menu to select the options:

Current Locale (UTF-8);
Western (ISO 8859-15);
Unicode (UTF-16)

The text of the particular document I opened is fine about two-thirds of the way down but beneath that it is all filled with lines of what look like Chinese characters.

The lower button with the drop-down menu is defaulted to the "Current Locale" option. I'm guessing it's somehow a matter of selecting the Unicode option from this list but when I select this, and then click on either "Retry" or "Edit Anyway", the button automatically switches back to the "Current Locale" option and nothing changes.

I opened another NotePad document which is also in Unicode and had no problems at all opening and editing that one. The problems occurred when I opened the second document, which has similar content to the first.

Another strange thing which happens is that the editor slows right down when I scroll down to the section filled with "Chinese" looking characters.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In case if you can share the Notepad document, please do so.

Comment: What editor are you using to open the files?

Comment: @CarlH I guess Allan is using Notepadqq since it is mentioned in the tags.

Comment: @Carl H I'm using Text Editor.

Comment: @technastic_tc No sorry I added that because I thought it referred to Windows Notepad. I'll remove it if possible.

Comment: @technastic_tc Sorry the content of the files is of a personal nature.

Comment: @Allan You can use the edit feature to change tags. I hope 'Text Editor' refers to gedit.

Comment: What is the encoding used for the Notepad document? Is it UTF-8 or UTF-16 or something else?

Comment: If you can add screenshots of the error messages, please do so. It can be helpful.

Comment: @technastic_tc Text Editor is the name of the program. It's the one that comes with Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @technastic_tc I'm not sure which encoding it is. I remember it was Unicode but not sure which one. The content is copy-and-pasted MSMs from a phone. When I saved the document after adding texts with special characters (probably emoticons) I was given the option of saving it in a Unicode format.

Comment: @technastic_tc Okay so somebody edited my question and added "gedit" so apparently that's what it is, though on my Ubuntu desktop menu it is called Text Editor.

Comment: @Allan Ok. Refer this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit

Comment: technastic_tc I added a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: @Allan What is MSMs?

Comment: @Allan It's me who edited the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111589/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-allan).